# Centering a table with text-align center

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to center a table, but although it's technically centered, the different length of the td's content makes the table have an empty space on the right.

```css
.wrap {
  background: pink;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  tr {
    td {
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>something here</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2 my </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1 hello world</td>
        <td>react.js</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I can make the `table` and the `td` to be an aligned center but the different length of the td's content makes it look uneven.

```css
.wrap {
  background: pink;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  tr {
    td {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>something here</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2 my </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1 hello world</td>
        <td>react.js</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What I want is td's content should be align left and look center within the wrapper, like the labels on this image (i.e. Cam 1, Cam 2 etc):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how the image relates to the table layout in your code snippet?

Comment: I think you need javascript to calculate the width of the table - not setting it to 100%, then make it center using margin:0 auto; the tds are text-aligned: left;

Comment: @FluffyKitten I try to translate from the image to html and css.

Comment: The image you include is a pie chart - how does that relate to a table display?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `width: 50%` to `<td>` to make it of equal widths, like:

```
tr td {
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  background: pink;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

tr td {
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>something here</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2 my </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1 hello world</td>
        <td>react.js</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this look weird though, in the graphic you can cearly see this doesn't look similar or close to the design.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out what you want... you want the text left-aligned but the *column* of text to be centered.

You can't do that with just HTML and CSS the way you have it structured, because each column isn't treated as a single unit in order to find the width to centre it.

For a pure HTML & CSS solution, you would have to restructure your table so that it treats the content of each column as a whole. You can display it as a `<ul>`, `<p>`, or even another table, e.g.

**Working Snippet:**

```css
.wrap {
    background: pink;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    tr{
        td {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
}

.cellcontainer {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}

td { border: 1px solid #555555; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="cellcontainer">
                        <p>something here</p>
                        <p>row 2 col 1 hello world</p>
                </div>
            </td>
             <td>
                <div class="cellcontainer">
                        <p>row 1 col 2 my</p>
                        <p>react.js</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I've added a border to the table columns so you can see that the left-aligned content is centered within the column.

If changing the structure of your HTML isn't possible, you would need to use something like javascript to achieve this.

Comment: this isn't look the same with the design above.

Comment: @CeciliaChan The design above is a pie chart - please see my comment on your question asking you to explain what your requirements are... your question is very unclear, as you can see by the answer you got.

Comment: @CeciliaChan I think I've workd out what you want to do, I've updated my answer, so take a look at the snippet and let me know if thats the layout you're looking for

Comment: change the structure is a bad idea, I use javascript loop to generate my table.

Comment: @CeciliaChan If you show us the javascript for generating the table, I can change it to make it work with the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the width of the table using javascript/jquery to have a better control with it. Check [this](https://jsbin.com/tonimul/edit?html,output) sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <style>

    table {
      margin : 0 auto;
      background-color:#DDDDDD;
    }
    table tr td {
      padding : 10px;
      text-align:left;

    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td> * Sample content</td>
      <td> * Sample content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> * Sample content</td>
      <td> * Sample content</td>
    </tr>   
  </table>
  <script>

      $(document).ready( function() {

        $('#myTable').css({
          width: $('#myTable').outerWidth() + 'px'
        });

      });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: uh? get the width then?

Comment: yes - check the tables width via jquery,. I believe that your table doesn't have a specific width because it depends on the content of your tds

Comment: what to do with the width then? post a full answer not how to do width()

Answer (score 0):

Your question is complicated and unclear . But as I understood, you want to center a table not it's td's text. For that you can use `margin:auto` on your table and remove `text-align:center` and add `width` to your table (because full width cannot be centered), then your table will center without any `.wrapper`.

Example

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cam 1</td>
        <td>Cam 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cam 3</td>
        <td>Cam 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

table tr td {
    border: 1px solid black; /* Added Border, Remove It */
}
```

Added border to td, so you can check td's text alignment. And also changed td text (Sorry for that).

Answer (score 0):

Align not the cells in the table, but the table itself.
For `<td>` to be of the same width, the table must be with the `table-layout: fixed;`:

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 24px;
}

table {
  background: pink;
  table-layout: fixed;
  tr {
    td {
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
}

/* debug */

body:before {
  content:'' ;
  border-right: solid 1px red;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  Diagram
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>something here</td>
        <td>row 1 col 2 my </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2 col 1 hello world</td>
        <td>react.js</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```